# Dealing with time zones for a day

Tags: php

I set the month, day and year like this:

```
$mm = date("m");
$yy = date("Y");
$day = date("d");
```

And then in a mysql query I select based on $day.

How do I deal with time zones? If someone in california runs this at 11pm their time it will be incorrect (my server is EST).

I tried to use offset but this changed the whole day ahead.
This does not work

```
$offest = '+1';
$day = date('d', strtotime($offset));
```

That just changes the date regardless of time.

I do have the fields stored as datetime.

Comment: You can see the correct use of strtotime() at http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php.  If you want to get really complex you can use the DateTime class http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.settimezone.php.

Comment: `$offest` does not equal `$offset`, a typo in the question?

Answer (score 1):

use function time()
example:

```
time()+3600(1 hours)
$date = date('d',time);
```